# Android menu icon smaller in honeycomb

Tags: android, menu, icons, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've created a menu icon and included a 36x36, 48x48 and 72x72 in the ldpi, mdpi and hdpi drawable folders. It looks fine on all devices except honeycomb tablets, where it seems like the padding around the Android icons are bigger than on my custom icon. I've included a screenshot (see how much bigger my 'Resume Reading' icon is than the android 'Back' and 'My Library' icons are). How do I make my icon look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. When using the Android resource icon's on a tablet, I think it changes the padding in order for the icon to be used in the action bar. So when displaying them in a pop up menu at the bottom they are appearing much smaller than they should be. The solution is to copy the android resources into our own resource folder as it says to do here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html

Comment: Awesome! Nevermind my previous comment then. :) Glad you were able to find a solution.

Comment: P.S. If this is the answer, you should accept yourself as the answer giver. This way others don't try and answer it for you.

Comment: LOL. Well, such is the way of life. I find this information useful, so I'll upvote it. Not everyone knows that padding is changed in that manner. Plus it has a great link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of your Tablets are not hdpi, they are xhdpi. While the [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) are useful, they don't give the whole story. Consider reading [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Here, they tell you further ratios and dimensions. To save you some time, resources should be 3ldpi:4mdpi:6hdpi:8xhdpi meaning that your xhdpi icon should be 96 x 96. Please, read the whole document, though. It is insanely useful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't think that is the problem. I have read through that document and it even says in it "By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device." So even if it is an xhdpi screen it should still be showing up the right size. I tried putting in a 96 x 96 icon in the drawable-xhdpi just to make sure and it's still the same size.

Comment: In that case, we will need to see the Layout file or Layout code. One of the two is inhibiting the size in some way.